# Simple encode decode function for Javascript and VBScript .ASP

Tags: javascript, encryption, vbscript

I am looking for a simple string encode/encrypt for some of the string values in a XML WebService output (IIS7 VBScript ASP) the agent is SmartPhones (JavaScript - PhoneGap).

One Caveat the data might be in a locale language or UTF-8.. (But I might have other ways to handle this)

Also ideally I would like the string to not have the same length..

The string is Quiz answers that just do not need to be human readable, no National Security concerns.. :-)

Thanks in advance
Kim

Comment: Post code. Nobody will write this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would just be to use the [split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx7f2xey) with the [reverse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47y5te1), as well as a little [CSS obfuscation](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/protecting-email-with-css/).